# Elegant way to add exceptions to s3 bucket deny policy using StringNotLike condition for specific actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have something like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:userId": [
            "AROAEXAMPLEID:*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want to only allow the user `"AROAEXAMPLEID:*"` N specific actions, e.g. `GetObject` and `PutObject`. Using some kind of syntax like this:

```
       "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:userId": [
            "AROAEXAMPLEID:*"
          ] // AND
          "aws:action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
          ]
        }
```

It seems to me that the only other way is to have a separate `Deny` statement for **every action type** separately? (so not use `"s3:*"`).  But this is nasty since to ensure the Deny works on all the *other* actions, I need one statement for every other action (and there are like 2 dozen for s3).

Comment: Is using _allow_ policies and relying on implicit denial not an option for you? The main inflexibility, in my view, is that explicit deny policies are evaluated first and take precedence over all other policy evaluations. I believe your assessment is correct that you would need to avoid denying the specific action you want this user to have; in this case, by denying every _other_ action. However, you _can_ have multiple actions in a single statement. So, it shouldn't require writing dozens of statements. Just one statement with many actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:userId": [
            "AROAEXAMPLEID:*"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "NotAction": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:userId": [
            "AROAEXAMPLEID:*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: So a `Deny` with a `NotAction` takes precedence over a `Deny` with an `Action`?  I'll give it a try ... do you have a link to any documentation that asserts the precedence rules here?

Comment: Also what if we had multiple actions? Say `GetObject` and `PutObject`, if we had two `Deny` with `NotAction` wouldn't each one cancel the other out (since `PutObject` is not `GetObject`)?

Comment: @samthebest No, precedence doesn't matter here. Notice the condition is `StringLike` instead of `StringNotLike`

Comment: @samthebest If you want to whitelist multiple actions, you can just add to `NotAction` list. You don't need a separate statement.

Comment: Thanks @jellycsc I get it now.  Though I may (though not clear from OP) want userX with `GetObject` and userY with `PutObject`, in that situation I think it's impossible without several Deny statements for each action type.  In your approach at least I can group together similar users into single statements.

Comment: And has the benefit of being future proof (in case new actions arise)

Comment: In fact, couldn't you achieve the same thing in your example more simply by using `"Principal": { "AWS" : [ <userArn> ] }`, and omit the `Condition` altogether?

Comment: I haven't tried, but I think moving it to `Principal` should have the same effect.